# Linked Lists and Try/Catch

Tags: java, linked-list, try-catch

so the question reads:

```
Create a Employee class which cannot be instantiated and has the following      fields:

• String name;
• String ppsNumber;
• int employeeNumber;
• int numberOfEmployees;
• protected double pay;

These data members are tracked using appropriate setter and getter methods.  Hourly
employees are paid €15.00 per hour and commission based employees are paid  10% of the
value of their sales figure. In the class you are required to appropriately  plan for a earnings
method (double earnings() and ensure that the method must be implemented in  subclasses.

Create a HourlyEmployee class and a CommissionEmployee class that are derived from
Employee. In each of these classes, create an overridden method named earnings.

Finally, you are required to test your classes using a client class and to  store the instances of
employees into a LinkedList, using try/catch blocks where appropriate.
```

I have most of the work done just getting stuck on the end of it, I've a few mistakes made somewhere in it, here it is:

```
public abstract class Employee {

    //private instances
    private String name;
    private String ppsNumber;
    private int employeeNumber;
    private int numberOfEmployees;
    protected double earnings;
    protected double pay;
    protected double sales;

//default constructor
public Employee(String name, String ppsNumber, int employeeNumber, int    numberOfEmployees, double earnings, double pay, double sales) {
    name = "Not Given";
    ppsNumber = "Not Givwn";
    employeeNumber = 0;
    numberOfEmployees = 0;
    earnings = 0;
    pay = 0;
    sales = 0;
}

//getters and setters
public String getName(){
    return name;
}   
public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPPSNumber(){
    return ppsNumber;
}   
public void setPPSNumber(String ppsNumber){
    this.ppsNumber = ppsNumber;
}

public int getEmployeeNumber(){
    return employeeNumber;
}   
public void setEmployeeNumber(int employeeNumber){
    this.employeeNumber = employeeNumber;
}

public int getNumberOfEmployees(){
    return numberOfEmployees;
}   
public void setNumberOfEmployees(int numberOfEmployees){
    this.numberOfEmployees = numberOfEmployees;
}

public double getPay(){
    return pay;
}   
public void setPay(double pay){
    this.pay = pay;
}

public double getEarnings(){
    return earnings;

}
public void setEarnings(double earnings){
    this.earnings = earnings;
}

public double getSales(){
    return sales;
}
public void setSales(double sales){
    this.sales = sales;
}

//calculateEarnings method
abstract double calculateEarnings();

//toString method
@Override
public String toString(){
    return name + ppsNumber + getEmployeeNumber();
}

}//end class
```

.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HourlyEmployee extends Employee {
    public HourlyEmployee(){
        super();        
    }

    //constructor
    public HourlyEmployee(String name, String ppsNumber, int employeeNumber, int numberOfEmployees, double earnings, double pay){
        super(name, ppsNumber, employeeNumber, numberOfEmployees, earnings, pay,  pay);
    }

    //calculate earnings method
    @Override
    double calculateEarnings() {
        //input hours worked to calculate earnings
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Hours Worked: ");
        pay = input.nextDouble();
        //calculate earnings
        earnings = pay * 15;
        System.out.println("Employee's Earnings: " + earnings);
        return earnings;

    }//end method
}//end class
```

.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CommissionEmployee extends Employee {
    public CommissionEmployee(){
        super();
    }

    //constructor
    public CommissionEmployee(String name, String ppsNumber, int employeeNumber, int numberOfEmployees, double earnings, double sales){
        super(name, ppsNumber, employeeNumber, numberOfEmployees, earnings, sales, sales);
    }

    //calculate earnings methods
    @Override
    double calculateEarnings() {
        //input sales value to calculate earnings
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Sales Value: ");
        sales = input.nextDouble();
        //calculate earnings
        earnings = sales * 0.1;
        System.out.println("Employee's Earnings: " + earnings);
        return earnings;

    }//end method
}//end class
```

.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;
import java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class EmployeeTester {

     public static void main(String[] args){

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            int numberOfEmployees = 0;

            while (numberOfEmployees == 0){
                try{
                   System.out.print("Enter Number of Employees: ");
                   numberOfEmployees = input.nextInt();
                } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                    System.out.println("Exception Thrown " + e);
                } 
               input.nextLine();//clears input
            }//end while

            Employee[] employees = new Employee[numberOfEmployees];

            //create linked list
            List<Employee> employeeList = new LinkedList<Employee>();

            //declare & create an HourlyEmployee
            employeeList.add(new HourlyEmployee());

            for(int i=0; i<employees.length; i++){

                String name;
                String ppsNumber;
                int employeeNumber;
                int x = 0;

            System.out.print("Name: ");
            name = input.next();
            System.out.print("PPS Number: ");
            ppsNumber = input.next();
            System.out.print("Employee Number: ");
            employeeNumber = input.nextInt();     

            employeeList.get(x).setName(name);

            x++; //increment x


                try{//if not using length to control loop
                    employees[i].setName(name);
                    employees[i].setPPSNumber(ppsNumber);
                    employees[i].setEmployeeNumber(employeeNumber);
                } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    System.out.println("Array Index Out of Bounds");
                }

            }//end for

            //enhanced for loop
            for(Employee element:employees){
                System.out.println(element.toString());
                System.out.println(element.calculateEarnings());
            } 


            //declare & create an CommissionEmployee
            employeeList.add(new CommissionEmployee());

            for(int i=0; i<employees.length; i++){

                String name;
                String ppsNumber;
                int employeeNumber;
                int x = 0;

            System.out.print("Name: ");
            name = input.next();
            System.out.print("PPS Number: ");
            ppsNumber = input.next();
            System.out.print("Employee Number: ");
            employeeNumber = input.nextInt();     

            employeeList.get(x).setName(name);

            x++; //increment x


                try{//if not using length to control loop
                    employees[i].setName(name);
                    employees[i].setPPSNumber(ppsNumber);
                    employees[i].setEmployeeNumber(employeeNumber);
                } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    System.out.println("Array Index Out of Bounds");
                }

            }//end for

            //enhanced for loop
            for(Employee element:employees){
                System.out.println(element.toString());
                System.out.println(element.calculateEarnings());
            } 

        }//end main()
}//end class
```

so originally my problem was i was when I ran the code it'll ask how many employees and will ask for name, pps number and employee number, then I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at EmployeeTester.main(EmployeeTester.java:54)
```

then I realized I forgot to add in constructors for hourlyemployees and commissionemployees, so I went an did that, now there's an error with the super class:

```
public class HourlyEmployee extends Employee {
public HourlyEmployee(){
    super();        
}
```

the error reads

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The constructor Employee() is undefined

at HourlyEmployee.<init>(HourlyEmployee.java:5)
at EmployeeTester.main(EmployeeTester.java:31)
```

and i still have the first problem, if anyone could help me to fix it and get the code running again that'd be great, thanks in advance

Comment: In order to be able to call `super();` the super class needs to have a constructor with no parameters, eg: `public  Employee(){}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are calling the constructor of your "father" with parameters:

```
public HourlyEmployee(String name, String ppsNumber, int employeeNumber, int numberOfEmployees, double earnings, double pay){
    super(name, ppsNumber, employeeNumber, numberOfEmployees, earnings, pay,  pay);
}
```

Which is fine, because you have defined it:

```
public Employee(String name, String ppsNumber, int employeeNumber, int    numberOfEmployees, double earnings, double pay, double sales) {
    name = "Not Given";
    ppsNumber = "Not Givwn";
    employeeNumber = 0;
    numberOfEmployees = 0;
    earnings = 0;
    pay = 0;
    sales = 0;
}
```

But here you are calling your "fathers" constructor without parameters, which is not defined anywhere:

```
public HourlyEmployee(){
    super();        
}
```

And that is exactly what the error message is telling you.

What you (most likely) really want is the following:

```
public Employee() {
    //note that in your code you didn't used the parameters anyway
    name = "Not Given";
    ppsNumber = "Not Givwn";
    employeeNumber = 0;
    numberOfEmployees = 0;
    earnings = 0;
    pay = 0;
    sales = 0;
}

public Employee(String name, String ppsNumber, int employeeNumber, int    numberOfEmployees, double earnings, double pay, double sales) {
    this.name = name;
    this.ppsNumber = ppsNumber;
    this.employeeNumber = employeeNumber;
    this.numberOfEmployees = numberOfEmployees;
    this.earnings = earnings;
    this.pay = pay;
    this.sales = sales;
}
```

Comment: that creates a duplicate method Employee...you meant for me to put it in the Employee section right??

Comment: Yes this is supposed to be inside the class. And it is okay to have multiple "functions" (constructor in this case) with the same name. Google: function overloading.

Answer (score 1):

Some issues I noticed (Assuming that this is line 54):

```
try{//if not using length to control loop
                employees[i].setName(name);
                employees[i].setPPSNumber(ppsNumber);
                employees[i].setEmployeeNumber(employeeNumber);
            }
```

In this code, you are assuming that the objects stored within the `employees` array are initialized, which they are not. You would need to do something like so

```
try{//if not using length to control loop
                employees[i] = new HourlyEmployee(); //or some other employee.
                employees[i].setName(name);
                employees[i].setPPSNumber(ppsNumber);
                employees[i].setEmployeeNumber(employeeNumber);
            }
```

Secondly, this error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The constructor Employee() is undefined` implies that the `Employee` class does not have a parameterless constructor. In Java, by default each object has a parameterless constructor, but when you provide your own, this gets removed.

Thus, you need to create a new parameterless constructor within your `Employee` class.

EDIT: As a side note, although it is good to show what you have tried, please refrain from providing all your code when asking future questions, but rather provide only what is relevant and suppliment it with some code which shows the problem.